# Proper optimization of some calculation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, linear-algebra

Trying to optimize a piece of code with numpy, I am wondering if this is the right approach.

Here is the formula of the computation 
, the matrix being lower-triangular.

[image: 1]

And here is my attempt:

```
(np.sum(P) - np.trace(P)) / np.sum(((t[np.newaxis]).T - t) * P)
```

Is this as good as it can get or can you see a more efficient way ?

Comment: There seems to be `p` and `P`. Is that intended or is there a typo?

Comment: Thanks Divakar, it was a typo (edited). I am concerned about the part (t[np.newaxis]).T - t) as I think it will create another n*n matrix, isn't that correct ? So in this case conciseness is or is not the proper approach ?

Comment: Please do not recommend Code Review unless you planning on writing an answer there.  If you don't have `numpy` related rep points on CR you don't know what is a good fit.  This is not fully working copy.  And don't be confused by different uses of the term 'optimization'.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Please take a look at Code Review's [help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). A question like this in it's current form is unacceptable at Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottleneck seems to be the computation of the denominator and seems like [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) should help there as we are performing element-wise multiplication and sum-reduction. Thus, the denominator could be computed like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,ij',t[:,None]-t, P)
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [414]: N = 5000
     ...: P = np.random.rand(N,N)
     ...: t = np.random.rand(N)
     ...: out = (np.sum(P) - np.trace(P)) / np.sum(((t[np.newaxis]).T - t) * P)
     ...: 

# Original method    
In [415]: den1 = np.sum(((t[np.newaxis]).T - t) * P)

# Proposed method    
In [416]: den2 = np.einsum('ij,ij',t[:,None]-t, P)

In [417]: np.allclose(den1, den2)
Out[417]: True

In [419]: %timeit np.sum(((t[np.newaxis]).T - t) *P)
10 loops, best of 3: 86.9 ms per loop

In [420]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij',t[:,None]-t, P)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.7 ms per loop
```

For the numerator, it seems most of the runtime is spent on `np.sum(P)`   :

```
In [422]: %timeit (np.sum(P) - np.trace(P))
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop

In [423]: %timeit np.sum(P)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
```

So, we can leave the numerator as it is.